# Working with Choice Flow in Mule Server 3.8.1(Anypoint Studio 6.2.1)

Tags: mule, mule-component

I am new to Mule and trying to learn the nuances on how the product work. As part of few experiments that I am trying out, I happened to try the Choice flow. But I could not get to work. It is always giving an XML error when I try to use that in my Mule flow. Also the editor will not allow me to add flow elements when I drag the choice from palette. I always need to work on the XML to get it showing in the Message flow editor. It might be a simple thing, but I am finding it difficult to figure out what is wrong here. The sample that I am trying is given below. Its just printing out the greeting based on the language posted from an http request. But its not working.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<mule xmlns:tracking="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking"
xmlns:http="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core"
xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/http/current/mule-http.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/tracking/current/mule-tracking-ee.xsd">
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" />
<flow name="choiceandbatchFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <expression-filter  expression="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.request.uri' != '/favicon.ico']" doc:name="Expression" /> 
    <set-variable variableName="language" value="#[message.inboundProperties.'http.query.params'.language]" doc:name="Set Language Variable" />
    <choice doc:name="Choice">          
        <when expression="#[flowvars.language=='spanish']">                 
            <set-payload value="Hola!" doc:name="Reply in Spanish" />           
        </when>         
        <when expression="#[flowvars.language=='french']">              
            <set-payload value="Bonjour!" doc:name="Reply in French" />           
        </when>
        <otherwise>                 
            <set-variable variableName="language" value="English"
                doc:name="Set Language to English" />    
            <set-payload value="Hello!" doc:name="Reply in English" />        
        </otherwise>
    </choice>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" />
</flow>
</mule>
```

I am getting the following error

```
ERROR 2017-01-14 15:05:30,016 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: null
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'when' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidComplexType(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleDocumentLoader.loadDocument(MuleDocumentLoader.java:86) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MuleArtifactContext.java:192) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:108) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:104) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:177) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:100) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:198) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:63) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:136) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:58) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.redeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:544) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.redeployModifiedArtifacts(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:555) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.redeployModifiedApplications(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:532) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.run(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:348) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_101]
INFO  2017-01-14 15:05:30,016 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication: App 'choiceandbatch' never started, nothing to dispose of
ERROR 2017-01-14 15:05:30,052 [Mule.app.deployer.monitor.1.thread.1] org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer: 
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
+ Failed to deploy artifact 'choiceandbatch', see below    +
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException: SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'when' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:207) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper$2.execute(ArtifactWrapper.java:63) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.executeWithinArtifactClassLoader(ArtifactWrapper.java:136) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.artifact.ArtifactWrapper.init(ArtifactWrapper.java:58) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArtifactDeployer.deploy(DefaultArtifactDeployer.java:25) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DefaultArchiveDeployer.redeploy(DefaultArchiveDeployer.java:544) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.redeployModifiedArtifacts(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:555) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.redeployModifiedApplications(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:532) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.run(DeploymentDirectoryWatcher.java:348) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_101]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_101]
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 18 in XML document from URL [file:/C:/Backup/Personal/Mobile/MyWorkspace/.mule/apps/choiceandbatch/choiceandbatch.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'when' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException) (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:198) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Line 18 in XML document from URL [file:/C:/Backup/Personal/Mobile/MyWorkspace/.mule/apps/choiceandbatch/choiceandbatch.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'when' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only. (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:49) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:198) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException: Line 18 in XML document from URL [file:/C:/Backup/Personal/Mobile/MyWorkspace/.mule/apps/choiceandbatch/choiceandbatch.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'when' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:112) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:177) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:100) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:198) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 18 in XML document from URL [file:/C:/Backup/Personal/Mobile/MyWorkspace/.mule/apps/choiceandbatch/choiceandbatch.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'when' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:399) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MuleArtifactContext.java:192) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:108) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:104) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:177) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:100) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:198) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    ... 15 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'when' cannot have character [children], because the type's content type is element-only.
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.error(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator$XSIErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.reportSchemaError(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidComplexType(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.elementLocallyValidType(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.processElementContent(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.handleEndElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.xs.XMLSchemaValidator.endElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[?:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:76) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleDocumentLoader.loadDocument(MuleDocumentLoader.java:86) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadDocument(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:429) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:391) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:336) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:304) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:181) ~[spring-beans-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.MuleArtifactContext.loadBeanDefinitions(MuleArtifactContext.java:192) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:129) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:452) ~[spring-context-4.1.6.RELEASE.jar:4.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringRegistry.doInitialise(SpringRegistry.java:108) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.registry.AbstractRegistry.initialise(AbstractRegistry.java:104) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.createSpringRegistry(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:177) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.spring.SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(SpringXmlConfigurationBuilder.java:100) ~[mule-module-spring-config-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.autoConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:101) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AutoConfigurationBuilder.doConfigure(AutoConfigurationBuilder.java:52) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractConfigurationBuilder.java:43) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.config.builders.AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.configure(AbstractResourceConfigurationBuilder.java:69) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory$1.configure(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:89) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.doCreateMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:222) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.context.DefaultMuleContextFactory.createMuleContext(DefaultMuleContextFactory.java:81) ~[mule-core-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
    at org.mule.module.launcher.application.DefaultMuleApplication.init(DefaultMuleApplication.java:198) ~[mule-module-launcher-3.8.1.jar:3.8.1]
```

Also here is the situation when I add a choice element from the palette to the Message Flow. it will not allow me to add anything under the when construct to define Route message. I have to always paste the xml in the configuration XML for getting the flows showing up in the Message Flow[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BETb7.jpg)

Any help here is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem: Typing the condition you want to use in the *When* row is tricky.

Solution: 
Try following the instructions in [this example](https://docs.mulesoft.com/getting-started/content-based-routing#choice-router-and-constituent-message-processors) exactly. This sequence of steps isn't intuitive at all.

1. In Studio, **in the properties editor** click right below When. A dialog appears. Type and save the first condition. The first condition appears in the properties editor under When.
2. In the properties editor, below the first condition click in the next When row to bring up the dialog again. Type and save the second condition.

Gotchas: Do not use a soft return to type more than one condition in the dialog. Also, do not click the Otherwise option in the dialog for this example. Follow the instructions in the docs link above to fall through to the Otherwise code.

Re: the problem dragging the Set Payload, or other Components, from the palette to the canvas to connect to Choice, the trick is to drop the other component when you see an indicator. In the case of connecting to Choice a black vertical line appears momentarily as shown here: [image]

Comment: I am unable to bring up the dialog by clicking below the When construct. No dialog is coming up and I am not sure whether I am doing something wrong. The portion below is not clickable for some reason.

Comment: Sorry I commented before really trying out what is given in the example. I have given you the credits for helping me out here. So the key here is one need to define the flow by dragging and dropping your choice components to the editor before setting the route Message part. So basically stitching the components after building the flow.  Its not that intuitive. May be MuleSoft is working to get that corrected in their future releases.

Comment: Ah, tks for the key.